# 2D graphics in C# for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

To do custom 2D graphics in Java/Swing, I subclass JPanel and override paintComponent.

To do custom 2D graphics in Android, I subclass View and override onDraw.

To do custom 2D graphics in iOS, I subclass UIView and override drawRect.

How can I do the same thing in C# for a Windows Store (Win8.1) mobile app?  What I've found thus far on Google has not been promising. This [page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e842fc2c-fa6f-4449-8819-5dda3e5160b9/graphics-class-not-available?forum=winappswithcsharp) suggests that no such API exists unless I build my GUI in XAML or go with Direct2D in C++. Has anyone found an API for C# that gives the same flexibility I already have with Swing, Android, and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is right.  That functionality does not exist.  To get similar functionality you will have to make a `WriteableBitmap` and use that in your view.